# How to select all columns not containing a certain substring in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table with column names like that:

```
name,
name_raw,
item,
item_raw,
message,
message_raw
...
... etc.
```

How can I select every column that does not end with `_raw` dynamically?

Is something like this:

```
SELECT
   [SOME REGEX LOGIC HERE]
FROM
   mytable
```

or similar possible?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that dynamically?

Comment: There are a lot of columns. I thought it would be easier and leaner to just filter them via regex, but I'm kinda new to Postgres/sql, so please tell me if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: It does not make sense. SQL != OOP. Queries should be static if possible.

Comment: If there are so many columns that you are thinking of doing something like that, then your database schema is probably wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you have so many columns that you cannot write a (static) query, you probably have to change the schema of your db.

If you cannot change the schema, here's a quick and dirty solution that utilizes postgresql's JSON capabilities. It does not return a traditional table with multiple columns, instead it returns a single column that contains json objects which contain all the columns from the original table whose name ends with `_raw`.

```
SELECT (
    SELECT json_object_agg(key,value)
    FROM json_each(to_json(t))
    WHERE key ~ 'raw$'
) FROM mytable;
```

The idea is convert every row from `mytable` to a JSON object and then use JSON functions to filter the members of the object.

Answer (score 2):

Use the information schema e.g.

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema'
AND table_name   = 'mytable'
AND NOT column_name LIKE '%\_raw'
```

note because the underscore itself is a query wildcard it needs to be "escaped"